# Remove all inline styles from Intraweb region

Tags: css, delphi, intraweb

I have an IWRegion on an ancestor IW form that I use for common interface elements (it has it's own HTMLTemplate).

When I view the html output (using Chrome's Inspect element), the div generated by the IWRegion has inline styles, yet unlike an IWForm there are no properties (StyleRenderOptions.RenderSize etc..) to disable them, is there any way to disable these inline styles?

Answer (score 2):

On the TIWAppForm you have the property StyleSheet.
Link your style css to the property.

I name a IWRegion to regTopTitle and in the css sheet I set:

```
.REGTOPTITLECSS{
  border-top-width: 10px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: #808080;
  border-bottom-width: 10px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #808080;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

You can make your own css
When I run the page I get the css Like I want to the region.
I to this with intraweb 10.0.23

Comment: It didn't appear to work since it seems to require my css files to the root of the Files directory, also, you can only specify 1 css file in the form's Stylesheet. I have 3 regions on my ancestor form using css files specified in the form's HTML template, these styles work fine, apart from when I specify a region (directly) in the HTML template, rather than a specific label or link.

Answer (score 2):

I use to modify html page with JQuery.
To add a class:

```
$('#REGTOPTITLE').addClass('myClass');
```

Or:

```
$('#REGTOPTITLE').attr('class','myClass');
```

if you want to remove IntraWeb existing class, and so on.

You have to write your JavaScript code into your TEMPLATE html if you use it, or iniect it into the IWForm property:

```
YourIWForm.ExtraHeader.Text := '<script type="text/javascript"> .... </script>'
```

**To remove inline style:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#REGTOPTITLE').attr('style','');
});
</script>
```

Examine the HTML source page to find the "id" tag you need to manage.